# Maven dependencies issue?

Tags: java, docker, maven, centos

I created a Maven project on IntelliJ and it runs correctly. Now, I would like to run my project with Docker and without IntelliJ.

For this, I use this command : `docker run -it --rm --name my-maven-project -v /var/www/html/Recommandation/:/usr/src/mymaven -p 88:88 -w /usr/src/mymaven maven:latest /bin/bash -c "mvn clean install && java -jar target/Recommandation-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.exemple.demo.App"`

```sh
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  42.037 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-07-01T11:33:43Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Unable to initialize main class org.exemple.demo.App
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/vertx/core/Verticle
```

But there is a dependency resolution issue. Any idea ?

Here's my pom.xml :

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.exemple.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>Recommandation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.exemple.demo.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Recommandation</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Comment: This is a standalone project or you are referring to another project within your project?

Comment: No because I'm able to build my project. Here I just want to run it with Docker. (I'm also able to run it with IntelliJ). @TarunLalwani It's a standalone project but there is a lot of dependancies. I will put my full pom.xml.

Comment: I can't, to much code for stackoverflow... :-/

Comment: I would recommend you to see this article as well, https://phauer.com/2019/no-fat-jar-in-docker-image/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you did not include the dependencies into your jar.

You need to build an executable jar for that.

IntelliJ allows you to run jars by pulling the dependencies in the background, but if you want to run a jar from command line it needs to include its dependencies (or you need to reference them from an external directory).

Comment: Ok I will try to follow the explanation of Joe's link and I put RESOLVE if I manage to launch my project. thank you for the explanations.

Comment: It's working. Indeed, it seems easier to have the dependency references in the executable jar file. Thanks to @Joe for his reference.